# Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions and SharePointPnPCoreOnline not compatible

Tags: sharepoint-online, .net, azure-functions

I'm developing a simple Azure Function project that uses the NuGet package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (version 1.0.29) to trigger on incoming Azure Storage Queue message, and uses SharePointPnPCoreOnline (version 3.15.1911) to communicate with SharePoint Online.

I seems like the current version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions does not play well with SharePointPnPCoreOnline, because the former is dependent on Newtonsoft.JSON version 9.0.1, while the latter requires Newtonsoft.JSON >= 11.0.1.

I've tried setting up an Azure Function v1 (which is based on .NET Framework), but this causes my project not even to build:

> Error NU1107  Version conflict detected for Newtonsoft.Json.
>   Install/reference Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1 directly to project
>   FunctionApp5 to resolve this issue.
>   FunctionApp5 -> SharePointPnPCoreOnline 3.15.1911 -> Newtonsoft.Json (>= 11.0.1)
>   FunctionApp5 -> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29 -> Newtonsoft.Json
>   (=
>   9.0.1).

I found [a workaround](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/146) suggesting I could explicitly set the Newtonsoft.JSON version to an older one (in this case 10.0.2), like this:

> 

Doing this still causes my project not even to compile:

> Warning   NU1608  Detected package version outside of dependency
>   constraint: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29 requires
>   Newtonsoft.Json (= 9.0.1) but version Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.2 was
>   resolved.

Another attempt was to base my project on Azure Function v2 (which is based on .NET Core). This causes runtime errors, so I believe SharePointPnPCoreOnline may not be compatible with .NET Core:

> System.MissingMethodException HResult=0x80131513 Message=Method not
>   found: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String, System.String)'.
>   Source=OfficeDevPnP.Core StackTrace: at
>   OfficeDevPnP.Core.Diagnostics.Log.InitializeLogger() at
>   OfficeDevPnP.Core.Diagnostics.Log.Debug(String source, String message,
>   Object[] args) at
>   OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.EnsureToken(String siteUrl,
>   String realm, String appId, String appSecret, String acsHostUrl,
>   String globalEndPointPrefix) at
>   OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(String
>   siteUrl, String realm, String appId, String appSecret, String
>   acsHostUrl, String globalEndPointPrefix) at
>   OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(String
>   siteUrl, String appId, String appSecret) at
>   AzureFunction_v2App.Function1.Run(String myQueueItem, ILogger log) in
>   [snip]

Have anyone gotten Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions and SharePointPnPCoreOnline to play nicely together, and could perhaps share some insight on how to set up the project?

Comment: did you got a resolution on this?

Comment: @RaviKhambhati Unfortunately, no. I decided not to spend any more time on this, but find some other way to piece things together.

Comment: Thanks @kenneho Can I ask what approach you have finally opted ?

Comment: @RaviKhambhati, I decided to run the code on an on-premise server instead of in Azure Functions. This way I didn't have to fight the incompatible libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the version of Newtonsoft.JSON to 11.0.2. This will prompt warnings but it could compile and the project could work.

Please take a reference of below demo that I tested on my Azure tenant.

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/FunctionApp2/FunctionApp2/FunctionApp2.csproj

BR